# Passar valor de jquery para php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou buscando uma div de outra página e colocando na minha:

minha div:

```
  <div id="teste"></div>

script:
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#teste").load("http://www.home356.org/index.php #ip_filter");          
  </script>
```

Com este script o resultado da div #ip_filter na página index.php é carregado para a div #teste normalmente.

O conteúdo dessa div ip_filter é um endereço ip de quem acessa a index.php. Na minha página eu gostaria de colocar uma condição em php que se o endereço ip (valor que será trazido para div #teste) for x.x.x.x, fazer: echo = "alguma coisa". se não for x.x.x.x, fazer: echo = "outra coisa".

Acho que é possível fazer essa condição com javascript mesmo, mas o problema é que tem máquinas linux na rede utilizando navegador firefox e javascript desabilitado nestas máquinas.

Será que é possível fazer isso utilizando php?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer a condição com php porque o javascript pode estar desabilitado, mas a requisição com `load` utiliza javascript da mesma forma. o.o

Comment: Verdade, eu realmente não levei isso em consideração.
Na realidade o que eu quero é desabilitar a input abaixo e trocar o valor da placeholder se o ip que estiver na div #teste for x.x.x.x

  <div><input name="try" type="text" id="try" 
  placeholder="try"  value="" />

Sou novato na área (na verdade sou de redes rss, aprendendo des web), então poderia me ajudar com o código mesmo em javascript?

Comment: Entendi, respondido...

Answer (score 0):

**Não.** Você não consegue alterar na página via PHP após ela ter sido enviada pelo servidor.

Isso é possível no lado cliente (ex. JS, jQuery).

**Atualizando:**

O que você pode fazer é carregar a página `http://www.home356.org/index.php #ip_filter` antes da `div`, seja por `include` ou outro método, atribuir o IP à uma variável `$x` qualquer, fazer os IFs necessários e dentro da `div` fazer um `echo` com o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que entendi é uma verificação simples, você quer receber o IP e caso ele coincidir com o desejado, fazer algo ou não.

Método `Attr` do `J-query` faz alterações nas propriedades da tag e `val` altera o valor da mesma caso seja `input`, exemplo...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var ipVerify = '20.0.255.255';
  var ip = '20.0.255.255'; // no seu caso o resultado do load
  
  if(ip == ipVerify){
   $(".ip").attr('disabled', 'true');
   $(".ip").attr('placeholder', 'try');
   $(".ip").attr('id', 'try');
  }else{
  //caso for seja diferente
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ip" type="text">
```

**Problema**

`Javascript` é uma linguagem `client side`, então verificações importantes onde Ip´s são expostos, não é trabalho dele, e sim de uma linguagem `server-side`, se segurança for um problema grande no seu projeto, é melhor rever sua lógica